# How to test if a number is a power of 2?

Tags: haskell, bitwise-operators

I want to do a simple test for if a number is a power of 2 in Haskell for a case guard I am making.

The purpose is to determine whether a number is even (and not a power of 2), whether a number is odd, or whether a number is to the power of 2.

I want to do something like:

```
function n
  | n `mod` 2 == 1 = 1
  | if n is to the power of 2 = 2
  | otherwise = 0
```

I have looked at some threads but they all say to use the bitwise operator:

```
(n & (n - 1)) == 0
```

However it says

> Not in scope: ‘&’

when I try to do so, so am not sure if that is allowed in Haskell.

Comment: I wonder if GHC optimizes `mod 2` to a bitshift when appropriate?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Haskell has bitwise operations, but these have a slightly different name. Indeed, you can make a bitwise AND with the [**`(.&.) :: Bits a => a -> a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Bits.html#v:.-38-.) function.

You thus can make such check with:

```
import Data.Bits(Bits, (.&.))

isPower2 :: (Bits i, Integral i) => i -> Bool
isPower2 n = n .&. (n-1) == 0
```

Note that your proposed solution will include zero as a power of two as well. Indeed, if we evaluate the first 1'000 numbers, we get:

```
Prelude Data.Bits> filter isPower2 [0 .. 1000]
[0,1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512]
```

Answer (score 3):

One other way to do this would be to use the `logBase` function with base `2`.

```
isPot :: (RealFrac b, Floating b) => b -> Bool
isPot = ((==) <*> (fromInteger . round)) . logBase 2

Prelude> isPot 2048
True
Prelude> isPot 1023
False
Prelude> isPot 1
True
```

**Edit:**
OK before evaluating the code lets get the math behind it. The idea is simple. Any number which can be expressed as power of two means it's logarithm with respect to base 2 (`logBase 2`) is a whole number.

Accordingly we will use the `logBase 2` function. If we check it's type

```
Prelude> :t logBase 2
logBase 2 :: Floating a => a -> a
```

we see that the input number should be a member of the `Floating` type class. The `logBase 2` function gets composed with the previous function which is;

```
(==) <*> (fromInteger . round)
```

Now if we forget about the applicative operator `<*>` this can be rephrased as

```
\n -> n == (fromInteger. round) n
```

Now if we check the type of `round` function

```
Prelude> :t round
round :: (RealFrac a, Integral b) => a -> b
```

we see that the input also needs to be a member of `RealFrac` type class hence the `(RealFrac b, Floating b) =>` constraint in the type declaration of the `isPot` function.

Now regarding applicative operator `<*>`, it's actually very handy when you have a two parameter function such as `(==)` and need to feed the left (first parameter) with `x` and right with `g x`. In other words `f <*> g = \x -> f x (g x)`. The type signature of `<*>` is

```
Prelude> :t (<*>)
(<*>) :: Applicative f => f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

I would advise you to read the [Functors, Applicative Functors and Monoids](http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids#monoids) part of the Learn You a Haskell book.

Comment: Would you mind explaining the code a bit please - sorry I am not very good at haskell and it looks like some high level stuff. I am mostly confused about the (RealFrac b, Floating b) bit and the 2nd line has some syntax I haven't seen before

Comment: @DoubleRainbowZ I have edited my answer to include some explanation. It's basically very simple code if you know the Applicative functors. I have attached a link at the bottom for further guidance.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot, that definitely helps a lot :)